# Add bitmap on touchevent

Tags: android

I am developing an application on paint.My requirement is that whenever user touches on canvas it should add a bitmap on screen.

I m trying something this:-

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);
Canvas mcanvas=new Canvas();
mcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a method which draw two bitmaps over each

```
    public Bitmap PutoverBmp(Bitmap all, Bitmap scaledBorder) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    final int width = bmp.getWidth();
    final int height = bmp.getHeight();
    all = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = all.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_border, width, height,
            true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0, paint);
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

simple call like below

```
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);

bmp = PutoverBmp(bmp,bmp1);
```

Comment: i m getting null pointer exception on: all = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, true);                      bmp = PutoverBmp(bmp,bmp1);

Comment: because your bmp is null. what is the source image for bmp ? ? i'm guessing its nothing. bmp must be not null to draw over it..